# Programmatically save Excel table in opened window, into file

Tags: c#, .net, excel

So this is what I need to do

There is a program which connects to some server and fetches data from it at a speed of approximately 15-20 entries per second

Right at the moment when connection with the server has been established, an Excel window opens and all entries fetched from the server, are dynamically moved into that Excel table

However all that content remains in the RAM, i.e. Excel file itself is created only when we try to close that Excel window and 'Save As..' dialog appears

As you have probably understood, I don't want to save the file manually every time, and hence I need some way to programmatically save Excel table in an opened window, into a file

Is there any way of doing that ?

Comment: have you tried using EPPlus?

Comment: I had a brief look at EPPlus, but could not see any kind of solution to the problem. EPPlus is designed specifically for handling Excel tables, while my problem is basically about handling opened windows in the system

Comment: Does the Excel instance that has its table filled run on a server? And do you need to run this as a service, or will you run the program manually to save the Excel workbook?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running this on a server and you don't mind manually triggering the Excel save, then the you can create something that will connect to the Excel instance using Interop. The following will connect to the Excel instance and return an `Excel.Workbook` object for the specified workbook name:

```
private Excel.Workbook GetWorkbook(string workbookName)
{
    Excel.Window window = null;      // Excel window object from which application is grabbed
    Excel.Application app = null;    // Excel instance from which we get all the open workbooks
    Excel.Workbooks wbs = null;      // List of workbooks
    Excel.Workbook wb = null;        // Workbook to return
    EnumChildCallback cb;            // Callback routine for child window enumeration routine
    List<Process> procs = new List<Process>();           // List of processes

    // Get a full list of all processes that have a name of "excel"

    procs.AddRange(Process.GetProcessesByName("excel"));

    foreach (Process proc in procs)
    {
        // Make sure we have a valid handle for the window

        if ((int)proc.MainWindowHandle > 0)
        {
            // Get the handle of the child window in the current Excel process

            int childWindow = 0;
            cb = new EnumChildCallback(EnumChildProc);
            EnumChildWindows((int)proc.MainWindowHandle, cb, ref childWindow);

            // Make sure we got a valid handle

            if (childWindow > 0)
            {
                // Get the address of the child window so that we can talk to it and
                // get all the workbooks

                const uint OBJID_NATIVEOM = 0xFFFFFFF0;
                Guid IID_IDispatch =
                    new Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
                int res = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(childWindow, OBJID_NATIVEOM,
                    IID_IDispatch.ToByteArray(), ref window);

                if (res >= 0)
                {
                    app = window.Application;
                    wbs = app.Workbooks;

                    // Loop through all the workbooks within the current Excel window
                    // to see if any match

                    for (int i = 1; i <= wbs.Count; i++)
                    {
                        wb = wbs[i];

                        if (wb.Name == workbookName)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        wb = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // If we've already found our workbook then there's no point in continuing
        // through the remaining processes

        if (wb != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    Release(wbs);
    Release(app);
    Release(window);

    return wb;
}
```

The `Release()` methods called above simply set the references to null and call `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject()` on them, otherwise you end up with headless instances of Excel all over the place.

You'll also need the following to perform some of the functionality to grab windows:

```
private delegate bool EnumChildCallback(int hwnd, ref int lParam);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(int hWndParent, EnumChildCallback lpEnumFunc, ref int lParam);

[DllImport("Oleacc.dll")]
private static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(int hwnd, uint dwObjectID, byte[] riid, ref Excel.Window ptr);

private bool EnumChildProc(int hwndChild, ref int lParam)
{
    // Get the name of the class that owns the passed-in window handle

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(128);
    GetClassName(hwndChild, buf, 128);

    // If the class name is EXCEL7 then we've got an valid Excel window

    if (buf.ToString() == "EXCEL7")
    {
        lParam = hwndChild;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern int GetClassName(int hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);
```

Once you have the workbook then you can call `Workbook.SaveAs()` to save it.

Comment: Will that pop up the 'Save As..' dialog ? I should not trigger the Excel save manually, that should be done automatically by the program. (given the filename that we want Excel table to be saved into)

Comment: @mangusta You can prevent the Save As dialogue from popping up by using the `SaveAs()` call and specifying the filename in there. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(v=vs.100).aspx).